# User Defined function in python for detecting missing Values in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, function, func

```
    ST_NUM    ST_NAME     OWN_OCCUPIED  NUM_BEDROOMS
0   104.0     PUTNAM            Y           3.0
1   197.0    LEXINGTON         NaN          NaN
2     NaN    LEXINGTON          N           3.0
3   201.0    BERKELEY          NaN          1.0
4   203.0    BERKELEY           Y           NaN
```

this is my data frame. I wanted to create a user defined functions which returns the data frame which shows number of missing values in data frame by column  and row number of missing value.

output df should look like this.

col_name      index
 st_num         2
 st_num         6
 st_name        8
 Num_bedrooms   2 
 Num_bedrooms   5
 Num_bedrooms   7
 Num_bedrooms   8 .......

Comment: What does the user-defined function actually take in as arguments? also what have you tried?

Comment: Why a user-defined function, and not simply, with Pandas, something like `df[some_column].isna().sum()`?

Comment: function takes a dataframe and returns the column name which has null values,

Comment: it should return : col_name , no, of missing values  , index of missing values

Answer (score 3):

You can slice the index by the `isnull` for each column to get the indices. Also possible with stacking and groupby.

```
def summarize_missing(df):
    # Null counts
    s1 = df.isnull().sum().rename('No. Missing')

    s2 = pd.Series(data=[df.index[m].tolist() for m in [df[col].isnull() for col in df.columns]],
                   index=df.columns,
                   name='Index')
    # Other way, probably overkill
    #s2 = (df.isnull().replace(False, np.NaN).stack().reset_index()
    #         .groupby('level_1')['level_0'].agg(list)
    #         .rename('Index'))

    return pd.concat([s1, s2], axis=1, sort=False)


summarize_missing(df)
#              No. Missing   Index
#ST_NUM                  1     [2]
#ST_NAME                 0     NaN
#OWN_OCCUPIED            2  [1, 3]
#NUM_BEDROOMS            2  [1, 4]
```

Comment: instead of returning list of index, how can we return series of null value index.

Comment: @sniteshkumar I dont quite understand what you mean. There's not really a valid ouput `1,3` as you had in the question. That either needs to be made into the string `'1,3'` or those numbers need to be placed in some container. If you don't want a list remove the `.tolist()` call, but the `str` representation really isn't useful. But if it's just for visualization you change it to `','.join(map(str,df.index[m])) for m in ...`

Comment: thanks a lot, i got your point, but what if i don't want total number of missing values column  instead it should return only two column , column name  and  row number as a dataframe.  like  if col1 contains 3 missing value index 1,3,5 then it should return       col1  1 , col1   3,   col1 5 as a dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way:

```
m = df.isna().sum().to_frame().rename(columns={0: 'No. Missing'})
m['index'] = m.index.map(lambda x: ','.join(map(str, df.loc[df[x].isna()].index.values)))

print(m)
              No. Missing index
ST_NUM                  1     2
ST_NAME                 0      
OWN_OCCUPIED            2   1,3
NUM_BEDROOMS            2   1,4
```

Comment: col_name      index
 st_num         2
 st_num         6
 st_name        8
 Num_bedrooms   2 
 Num_bedrooms   5
 Num_bedrooms   7
 Num_bedrooms   8 ....... is it possible to return like this ?